# PHP mysql select query with CASE condition

Tags: php, mysql

I've restaurant, restaurant_time table. I need to show the restaurant is open or closed.

This is my query

```
$cur_nowtime = strtotime(date("H:i"));
$curDayOct   = strtolower(date("D"));

SELECT rest.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name, 
       restime.".$curDayOct."_status AS res_curr_ocday_status, 
       IF( ".$cur_nowtime." BETWEEN ".$curDayOct."_ot AND ".$curDayOct."_ct, 'Open','Closed') AS res_oct_status, 
       CASE WHEN res_curr_ocday_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
       WHEN res_oct_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
       ELSE 'Closed' END AS final_res_status
FROM restaurantAS rest 
LEFT JOIN restaurant_time AS restime ON rest.restaurant_id = restime.res_id
```

I need to get the restaurant openclose status in the field of "final_res_status" using 2 alies name "res_curr_ocday_status" and "res_oct_status"

I need to show the output as like below.

```
restaurant_id   restaurant_name res_curr_ocday_status   res_oct_status  final_res_status
1   aaa     Open    Closed  Closed
2   bbbb    Open    Open    Open
3   cccc    Closed  Closed  Closed
4   dddd    Closed  Open    Closed
```

Please see my query..

```
SELECT temp.*, (CASE WHEN temp.res_curr_ocday_status = 'Open' AND temp.res_curr_octime_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
ELSE 'Closed' END) AS res_oct_status FROM 
(SELECT rest.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name,
   restime.".$curDayOct."_status AS res_curr_ocday_status, 
   IF( ".$cur_nowtime." BETWEEN ".$curDayOct."_ot AND ".$curDayOct."_ct, 'Open','Closed') AS res_curr_octime_status,
   cty.cityname, zip.zipcode,
   ROUND( ( ( SUM(rvw.rating) / (COUNT(rvw.rating_id)*5) )*100 ) ,1) AS avg_rating
   FROM restaurant AS rest 
   LEFT JOIN restaurant_time AS restime ON rest.restaurant_id = restime.res_id 
   WHERE rest.restaurant_status = '1' GROUP BY rest.restaurant_id ORDER BY FIELD(res_oct_status, 'Open') DESC , FIELD(rest.restaurant_zip, '2600') DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0,10 ) AS temp
```

...  I'm getting "Unknown column 'res_oct_status' in 'order clause'"

Comment: I would rather separate the query and the presentation logic. It will reduce complexity of the code and will make maintenance easier. To do so, just have the `if conditions` in php, rather than in the SQL query.

Comment: try ORDER BY FIELD(temp.res_oct_status, 'Open') DESC

Comment: same error coming...

Comment: ORDER BY should be after `as temp`

Comment: ) as temp ORDER BY FIELD(res_oct_status, 'Open') DESC , FIELD(rest.restaurant_zip, '2600') DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0,10

Answer (score 0):

Try this (first one is your query that i modified, second one is my previous answer):

```
SELECT temp.*, (CASE WHEN temp.res_curr_ocday_status = 'Open' AND temp.res_curr_octime_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
ELSE 'Closed' END) AS res_oct_status FROM 
(SELECT rest.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name,
   restime.".$curDayOct."_status AS res_curr_ocday_status, 
   IF( ".$cur_nowtime." BETWEEN ".$curDayOct."_ot AND ".$curDayOct."_ct, 'Open','Closed') AS res_curr_octime_status,
   cty.cityname, zip.zipcode,
   ROUND( ( ( SUM(rvw.rating) / (COUNT(rvw.rating_id)*5) )*100 ) ,1) AS avg_rating
   FROM restaurant AS rest 
   LEFT JOIN restaurant_time AS restime ON rest.restaurant_id = restime.res_id 
   WHERE rest.restaurant_status = '1' GROUP BY rest.restaurant_id  ) AS temp ORDER BY FIELD(temp.res_oct_status, 'Open') DESC , FIELD(temp.restaurant_zip, '2600') DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

---

```
    SELECT temp.*, (CASE WHEN temp.res_curr_ocday_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
           WHEN temp.res_oct_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
           ELSE 'Closed' END) AS final_res_status FROM 
    (SELECT rest.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name, 
    restime.".$curDayOct."_status AS res_curr_ocday_status, 
    IF( ".$cur_nowtime." BETWEEN ".$curDayOct."_ot AND ".$curDayOct."_ct, 'Open','Closed') AS res_oct_status, 
    FROM restaurantAS rest 
    LEFT JOIN restaurant_time AS restime ON rest.restaurant_id = restime.res_id
LEFT JOIN city AS cty ON rest.restaurant_city = cty.city_id AND rest.restaurant_status = '1') as temp ORDER BY FIELD(final_res_status , 'Open') DESC
```

Comment: Its working..Thanks.. I need to add one more table with Left join & need to use WHERE condition also..LEFT JOIN city AS cty ON rest.restaurant_city = cty.city_id and where condition is WHERE rest.restaurant_status = '1' ORDER BY FIELD(final_res_status , 'Open') DESC. How to use?

Comment: Please add WHERE condition..... WHERE rest.restaurant_status = '1' ORDER BY FIELD(final_res_status , 'Open') DESC

Comment: @mikejohnvino already added.. see `rest.restaurant_city = cty.city_id AND rest.restaurant_status = '1'`

Comment: @mikejohnvino if it is working then please accept it so other users can get the answer

Comment: try **ORDER BY FIELD(temp.res_oct_status, 'Open') DESC** @mikejohnvino

Answer (score -1):

Use the following sql query:

```
SELECT temp.*, (CASE WHEN temp.res_curr_ocday_status = 'Open' AND temp.res_oct_status = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
       ELSE 'Closed' END) AS final_res_status FROM 
(SELECT rest.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name, 
restime.".$curDayOct."_status AS res_curr_ocday_status, 
IF( ".$cur_nowtime." BETWEEN ".$curDayOct."_ot AND ".$curDayOct."_ct, 'Open','Closed') AS res_oct_status, 
FROM restaurantAS rest 
LEFT JOIN restaurant_time AS restime ON rest.restaurant_id = restime.res_id) as temp
```

Comment: Its working..Thanks.. I need to add one more table with Left join & need to use WHERE condition also..LEFT JOIN city AS cty ON rest.restaurant_city = cty.city_id and where condition is WHERE rest.restaurant_status = '1' ORDER BY FIELD(final_res_status , 'Open') DESC. How to use?